# PHP CURL doesnt get the response, but CLI curl does

Tags: php, curl

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$out = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($out)
curl_close($curl);
```

This code output empty string.

If I execute from command line
curl http://myurl.com

I get the expected response, which is -1 in this case:

```
-1
* Connection #0 to host myurl.com left intact
```

Seems like cli and php curl have different behaviours. If I try `shell_exec` using the same cli command I get the expected response.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], please?

Comment: What is the output of `echo curl_error($curl);` after `$out = curl_exec($curl);` ?

Comment: is the URL secured (have https:// pefix)?